# C++ Program reading '*' as 'a'

Tags: c++, pointers, command-line, char, command-line-arguments

I am working on a short little calculator program that takes command line arguments and performs the relevant operations. It all works fine except with multiplication.

When I type "./calc 3 * 3" in the command line, the program spits out an error, and when I "cout" the char it stored as operator it says "a". All the other operators work fine.

Can you guys figure out why it's not accepting '*' as a char?

Here is the code and some sample output:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

const int MINIMUM_ARGUMENTS = 4; //must have at least 4 arguments: execution command, a first number, the operator, and a second number;

double Add(double x, double y);
double Subtract(double x, double y);
double Multiply(double x, double y);
double Divide(double x, double y);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < MINIMUM_ARGUMENTS) //"less than" because counting execution command as first argument
    {
        cout << "\nMust have at least " << MINIMUM_ARGUMENTS << " arguments (including execution command)." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        double num1 = atof(argv[1]); //stores first argument as double
        char operation = *argv[2]; //stores second argument (operator) as char
        double num2 = atof(argv[3]); //stores third argument - second number
        double result = 0; //will store result of arithmetic    

        cout << '\n';

        switch (operation) //determines which function to call based on the char (operator) argument
        {
        case '+':
            result = Add(num1, num2);
            cout << result << endl;
            break;
        case '-':
            result = Subtract(num1, num2);
            cout << result << endl;
            break;
        case '*':
            result = Multiply(num1, num2);
            cout << result << endl;
            break;
        case '/':
            result = Divide(num1, num2);
            cout << result << endl;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Error." << endl;           
        }   
    }

    cin.clear();
    cout << "\nPress enter to quit." << endl;
    cin.ignore();

    return 0;
}

double Add(double x, double y)
{
    return x + y;
}

double Subtract(double x, double y)
{
    return x - y;
}

double Multiply(double x, double y)
{
    return x * y;
}

double Divide(double x, double y)
{
    return x / y;
}
```

Sample Output:

```
-bash-4.1$ ./calc 10 - 5

5

Press enter to quit.

-bash-4.1$ ./calc 4 + 9

13

Press enter to quit.

-bash-4.1$ ./calc 10 / 2

5

Press enter to quit.

-bash-4.1$ ./calc 5 * 5

Error.

Press enter to quit.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The * sign is used by OS (bash here) to select all files from current dir. so change your sign.

I suggest 'x'

Comment: Or quote it. `'*'` or `\*` should do.

Answer (score 6):

While sending `*` use single quotes `'*'` or escape it using `\*`.

Simply `*` will not work because on command line `*` means "everything in the current directory".

Answer (score 3):

`*` is a wildcard that is used to select all . Generally used in selecting all files in a directory .

For example :

`delete *.exe`: This command would delete all the files with extension ".exe " from the folder .

If used in bash, `*` would be treated as a Wildcard, so you should consider some other sign to perform the required operation.